# SQL How to count items by association

Tags: mysql, sql

Table users

```
ID   name   country
---  -----  -----
100  John    1
101  Mark    4
102  Peter   3
103  Lucy    3
```

Table followers

```
ID   folowerId  followedId 
---  ---------  ------
 1   102         101
 2   103         101
 3   102         100
 4   100         101
 5   100         102
 5   103         100
```

Table country

```
ID   name 
---  -----
1    China
2    Usa
3    Italia
4    India
```

How to get the number of followers for a specific user grouped by country ?

Example output for user 101:

```
country   count
-------   -----
China      1 
Italia     2
```

I have tried this:

```
 SELECT 
     User.name, COUNT(Follower.id) AS FollowerCount 
 FROM 
    followers AS Follower 
    JOIN users AS User ON Follower.UserId = User.id 
 GROUP BY 
    User.country;
```

but it's not working

Comment: What have you tried?  This seems like a pretty basic `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a count and group by

```
select c.name, count(*) 
from followers b 
left join users  as a on b.folloswerId = a.id
left join country on a.country = c.id
where b.followedId  = 101
group by c.name
```